# Angular factory variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying simple Angular app and I have problem

```
var module = angular.module("app", []);
module.controller('Main', function ($scope, button) {
    $scope.displayText = button.dispText;

    $scope.increment = function () {
        button.increment();
        $scope.displayText = button.dispText;
    }

})


module.factory('button', function () {
    var displayText = '0';
    var intButton = 0;

    return {
        increment: function () {
            intButton++;
            displayText = intButton.toString()
        },
        getDisplayText: function () {
            return displayText;
        },
        dispText: intButton.toString()
    }
});
```

Whenever function increment is called variables in my factory get updated, but the value is not transfered to the controller. Why?

Comment: `$scope.displayText = button.dispText;` should be `$scope.displayText = button.getDisplayText();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function getDisplayText() from the factory and assign to the variable

```
    $scope.increment = function () {
     button.increment();
     $scope.displayText = button.getDisplayText();
   }
```